# how to compute emd flow by using cv.CalcEMD2 (opencv)?

Tags: python, opencv

I know MATLAB and C can compute EMD flow. However, I am trying to use python (opencv) to compute the EMD flow by using function cv.CalcEMD2. Is there any chance if anyone can give me an example using cv.CalcEMD2 or any function to get EMD flow please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some python code that computes EMD and the flow for two mixtures of Gaussians. I hope that helps.

```
"""
Compute earth mover's distance (EMD) to compare two mixtures of Gaussians

Requires: numpy, cv2, csb
"""
import numpy as np, cv2
from csb.numeric import log_sum_exp

class GMM(object):
    """
    1d mixture of Gaussians
    """
    def __init__(self, K):
        """
        K: number of components
        """
        self.mu = np.zeros(K)
        self.sigma = np.ones(K)
        self.w = np.ones(K)
        self.w/= self.w.sum()

    @property
    def K(self):
        return len(self.mu)

    def log_prob(self, x):
        logp = - 0.5 * np.subtract.outer(x, self.mu)**2 / self.sigma**2. \
           - 0.5 * np.log(2*np.pi*self.sigma**2) + np.log(self.w)

        return log_sum_exp(logp.T,0)

    def __call__(self, x, normed=True):

        logp = self.log_prob(x)
        if np.iterable(x) and normed:
            logp -= log_sum_exp(logp)

        return np.exp(logp)

    def randomize(self, mu_range=(-10, 10.), sigma_range=(0.1, 5.)):

        self.mu[...] = np.random.uniform(*mu_range, size=self.K)
        self.sigma[...] = np.random.uniform(*sigma_range, size=self.K)
        self.w[...] = np.random.random(self.K)
        self.w /= self.w.sum()

def make_signature(x, p):

    P = np.transpose([p,x])
    P64 = cv2.cv.fromarray(np.array(P.tolist()))
    P32 = cv2.cv.CreateMat(P64.rows, P64.cols, cv2.cv.CV_32FC1)
    cv2.cv.Convert(P64, P32)

    return P32

def calc_emd(q, p, x):

    Q = make_signature(x, q)
    P = make_signature(x, p)

    flow = cv2.cv.CreateMat(len(q), len(p), cv2.cv.CV_32F)
    cv2.cv.Set(flow, 0.)

    return cv2.cv.CalcEMD2(P, Q, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2, flow=flow), np.asarray(flow[:,:])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = np.linspace(-10., 10., 100)

    ## create two mixtures of Gaussians with 3 and 5 components

    f = GMM(3)
    g = GMM(5)

    f.randomize()
    g.randomize()

    ## evaluate mixtures on 1d grid

    q = f(x)
    p = g(x)

    ## compute EMD and flow

    emd, F = calc_emd(q, p, x)

    ## check marginals

    print np.fabs(F.sum(0) - q).max(), np.fabs(F.sum(1)-p).max()
```